# How can I get WHOIS records for domains with similar domains?

Tags: domain, whois

When I make a WHOIS query for `google.com` I get the following list of similar domains back:

```
$ whois google.com

Aborting search 50 records found .....
GOOGLE.COM.AFRICANBATS.ORG
GOOGLE.COM.ANGRYPIRATES.COM
GOOGLE.COM.AR
GOOGLE.COM.AU
GOOGLE.COM.BAISAD.COM
GOOGLE.COM.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
GOOGLE.COM.BR
GOOGLE.COM.CN
GOOGLE.COM.CO
GOOGLE.COM.DGJTEST028-PP-QM-STG.COM
GOOGLE.COM.DO
GOOGLE.COM.FORSALE
GOOGLE.COM.HACKED.BY.JAPTRON.ES
GOOGLE.COM.HANNAHJESSICA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.HAS.LESS.FREE.PORN.IN.ITS.SEARCH.ENGINE.THAN.SECZY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.HK
GOOGLE.COM.HOUDA.DO.YOU.WANT.TO.MARRY.ME.JEN.RE
GOOGLE.COM.IS.APPROVED.BY.NUMEA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET
GOOGLE.COM.LASERPIPE.COM.DOMAINPENDINGDELETE.COM
GOOGLE.COM.LOLOLOLOLOL.SHTHEAD.COM
GOOGLE.COM.MAIKO.BE
GOOGLE.COM.MX
GOOGLE.COM.MY
GOOGLE.COM.NOHAREKART.COM
GOOGLE.COM.NS1.CHALESHGAR.COM
GOOGLE.COM.NS2.CHALESHGAR.COM
GOOGLE.COM.PE
GOOGLE.COM.PK
GOOGLE.COM.SA
GOOGLE.COM.SHQIPERIA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SOUTHBEACHNEEDLEARTISTRY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SPAMMING.IS.UNETHICAL.PLEASE.STOP.THEM.HUAXUEERBAN.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SPROSIUYANDEKSA.RU
GOOGLE.COM.SUCKS.FIND.CRACKZ.WITH.SEARCH.GULLI.COM
GOOGLE.COM.TESTZZZZ.3000-RI.COM
GOOGLE.COM.TR
GOOGLE.COM.TW
GOOGLE.COM.UA
GOOGLE.COM.UK
GOOGLE.COM.UY
GOOGLE.COM.VABDAYOFF.COM
GOOGLE.COM.VN
GOOGLE.COM.WORDT.DOOR.VEEL.WHTERS.GEBRUIKT.SERVERTJE.NET
GOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.YUCEKIRBAC.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZNAET.PRODOMEN.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZ.GET.LAID.AT.WWW.SWINGINGCOMMUNITY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.GET.ONE.MILLION.DOLLARS.AT.WWW.UNIMUNDI.COM
GOOGLE.COM
```

Also, this message is attached:

> To single out one record, look it up with "xxx", where xxx is one of the
>   records displayed above. If the records are the same, look them up
>   with "=xxx" to receive a full display for each record.

So I try `whois "google.com"` but this returns the same response as above. If I try `whois "=google.com"` it gives me back whois results for all 50 results.

Is there a way to get WHOIS information for just `google.com`?

Comment: Use GNU jwhois, and you will never see this junk again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with the WHOIS protocol is quite messy.

At least for human digestion it's typically most practical to use a client that has been pre-configured in such a way that it can present a mostly consistent interface to the user.

Doing so means having a very extensive configuration with not only information about which servers to use for particular queries but also information about the quirks of specific servers.
Thankfully many popular clients ship with an already well-tuned configuration.

Just as an example (as your question was about a `com` domain name), I find this in my [`jwhois.conf`](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/jwhois/jwhois/example/jwhois.conf?view=markup) (I do not believe the linked version is really up to date, but it still serves as an example):

```
    "\\.com$" {
            whois-server = "whois.verisign-grs.com";
            query-format = "domain $*";
    }
```

Ie, for a query that ends in `.com` it uses the server `whois.verisign-grs.com` and prefixes the query with *domain*. Ie the query `google.com` is changed to `domain google.com`.

Do note that this particular query format is not applicable for all WHOIS servers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is simple to do.

```
whois "domain google.com"
```

This will give you just google.com results (exact match).

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear that this is possible with the CLI `whois` tool. However, some WHOIS web-based services will do this for you:

```
https://whois.domaintools.com/google.com
```